# How can I write a method that return an int from an array of buttons when one is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, button, return-value

I have a large array of numbered buttons that are used to get an integer. Is there anyway I could write a method which activates these buttons, waits until a user has clicked one, deactivates them, and return the integer that was pressed.

The method would be similar to JOptionPane.showInputDialog in that it brings up a UI then return an int (instead of a string) when the user makes an input.

Why do I want to do this instead of just running out the program through the listener class? Long story short this array of buttons is used to get ints for many different purposes and the code that runs afterward is very different depending on where in the program the buttons are used. I have written some of the code using a switch statement in the listener so that it runs the appropriate code. However it is getting incredibly hard to read and confusing to write. Having a method that returns an int as I have described above would greatly simplify the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a listener and add a new one. But if you want to work with return values you could use an ArrayBlockingQueue. The listener you add to your buttons could put the int value into the blocking queue. And in your main thread you can then take a value out of the queue. The take method will pause the main thread until a button was pressed.

Comment: Is an array blocking queue the best way to have my program wait until a button has been pressed?